# How to update record without objectID in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, postman

I am trying to update the record with *some other column name* instead of ObjectID but it's not working. How to resolve this issue?

```
router.put('/:InvoiceNo/', async (req,res)=>{
    if(req.body.FlagID==2){

        var InvoiceNo = parseInt(req.params.InvoiceNo);
        console.log(parseInt(req.params.InvoiceNo));
        var purchaseInvoice= new PurchaseInvoice({
            FlagID: req.body.FlagID,
            InvoiceNo:  req.body.InvoiceNo,
            RefNo:  req.body.RefNo,
            InvoiceDate:  req.body.InvoiceDate,
            VendorName: req.body.VendorName,
            GSTNo: req.body.GSTNo,
            VendorType: req.body.VendorType,
            Address: req.body.Address,
            State: req.body.State,
            TransportMode: req.body.TransportMode,
            TransportNumber: req.body.TransportNumber,
            PurchaseType: req.body.PurchaseType,
            DueDate: req.body.DueDate,
            DeliveryNote: req.body.DeliveryNote,
            Remarks: req.body.Remarks,
            Materials: req.body.Materials,
            Expenses: req.body.Expenses,
            Commission: req.body.Commission,
            Discount: req.body.Discount,
            Adjustment: req.body.Adjustment,
            GrandTotal: req.body.GrandTotal
        });

        **PurchaseInvoice.findByIdAndUpdate( {InvoiceNo : InvoiceNo} , { $set: req.body }, { useNewUrlParser: true, useFindAndModify: false }, (err, doc) => {**
            if (!err) { res.send(doc); }
            else { console.log('Error in Purchase Invoice Update :' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2)); }
        });
    }
});
```

I am facing this error:

```
Error in Purchase Invoice Update :{
  "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"{ InvoiceNo: 1001 }\" at path \"_id\" for model \"PurchaseInvoice\"",
  "name": "CastError",
  "stringValue": "\"{ InvoiceNo: 1001 }\"",
  "kind": "ObjectId",
  "value": {
    "InvoiceNo": 1001
  },
  "path": "_id"
}
```

With ObjectID it's working fine but without ObjectID I want to update the record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use the id, you should use findOneAndUpdate() (and not findByIdAndUpdate() :

```
await MyModel.findOneAndUpdate({}, { $set: { name: 'foo' } });
```

Otherwise, you should get the document you want to update first, with any query filter you want :

```
const purchaseInvoice = await PurchaseInvoice.findOne(< query filter >);
```

then update your document like a classic javascript object :

```
purchaseInvoice.FlagID = req.body.FlagID,
purchaseInvoice.InvoiceNo =  req.body.InvoiceNo,
purchaseInvoice.RefNo = req.body.RefNo, etc...

purchaseInvoice.save()
```

but it will use the _id behind the scene.